Error when modifying the vuetify theme in vue3
I have an error or well if you can call it that I want to change the primary and secondary color of the vuetify theme, I do it in the vuetify.js file as shown below.
// Styles
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import 'vuetify/styles'

// Composables
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'

// https://vuetifyjs.com/en/introduction/why-vuetify/#feature-guides
export default createVuetify({
  defaults: {
    theme: {
      themes: {
        light: {
          colors: {
            primary: '#1B3055',
            secondary: '#4984A1',
          },
        },
      },
    },
    VBtn: {
      class: 'text-none',
    },
}
})

but on the button I have a different color than the one posted
<v-btn :height="56" color="primary" variant="flat" class="mt-5 text-none"
:loading="loaderSession" @click="signIn()" block>
Iniciar Sesion
</v-btn>


I don't understand why this error happens to me. I already have several projects with vue and vuetify, but in this case I have this error, and if I already verified the theme, it is in light. the versions are "vue": "^3.3.0", "vuetify": "^3.4.0".
thanks
Solve my problem with vuetify

please post your code as formatted text, not images.

You should move theme out of defaults:
// Styles
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import 'vuetify/styles'

// Composables
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'

// https://vuetifyjs.com/en/introduction/why-vuetify/#feature-guides
export default createVuetify({
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        colors: {
          primary: '#1B3055',
          secondary: '#4984A1',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  defaults: {
    VBtn: {
      class: 'text-none',
    },
}
})

